# help with jquery ajax and templates in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-templates

So I have a complex form for an IncomeDeclaration.

Its going to display a textfield GrossIncome for each Activity that the IncomeDeclaration is related to... this all gets done on the server and works just fine.... the problem is. The User should also be able to add Activities on the fly.. through javascript... so when the user clicks on Add Activity a Dropdown and a textfield must be appended to the bottom the activities list... heres what Ive got so far

```
<tbody id="activities">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.income.EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations)

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="#" id="add_activity">Agregar Otra Actividad</a>

    </fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#add_activity").click(function () {

            $.getJSON('/IncomeDeclarations/GetEconomicActivities', function (data) {
                var select = new Select();
                var data = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var option = new Option(data[i]["name"], data[i]["i"])
                    //should do something here
                }


                //should call the template and append to #activities
            });
        });
</script>


    <script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td><select name="income.EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations[${SomeNumber}].EconomicActivityId">
        ${MyOptions}        
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="income.EconomicActivityIncomeDeclarations[${SomeNumber}].GrossIncome" /></td>>
    </tr>
</script>

}
```

The name attribute for both the select and the text_field is key for this to work... otherwise modelbinding wont work... I would think that if the SomeNumber variable is set to new Date.GetTime() model Binding should work just fine...

I actually dont see the need of ajax for this but thats another topic.. I just havent figured out a way to do this without ajax... 
right now I want to get the template to work and append the form elements to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: That looks much cleaner... I will try that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201845/problem-with-asp-net-mvc-modelbinding-behavior